# Google Calendar API returns events outside date range

Tags: google-calendar-api, date-range

I'm trying to select events for the next 2 weeks starting from today's date. 
The logic used is pretty easy. I get all calendars, then pick one i need to pull events from and supply the date range. I'm pulling dates from the selected calendar however it doesn't look like the date range is applied. Now, i have 2 events scheduled for the following dates.

- October 8
- October 20

I should only be getting event scheduled for October 20th, but i'm getting both.

```
        CalendarService calService = new CalendarService(calendarAppName);
        calService.setUserCredentials(username, password);

        CalendarQuery calQuery = new CalendarQuery();
        calQuery.Uri = new Uri("https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/owncalendars/full");
        CalendarFeed calFeed = (CalendarFeed)calService.Query(calQuery);

        var activeCalendar = calFeed.Entries.Where(x => x.Title.Text == calendarName).FirstOrDefault();
        if (activeCalendar != null)
        {
           EventQuery evtQuery = new EventQuery(GetCalendarFeed(activeCalendar));
           evtQuery.StartDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
           evtQuery.EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(14);
           evtQuery.FutureEvents = false;

           EventFeed evtFeed = calService.Query(evtQuery);
        }

        ...

        private static string GetCalendarFeed(AtomEntry calendarEntry)
        {
           string feedstring = calendarEntry.Id.AbsoluteUri.Substring(63);
           return string.Format("http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/{0}/private/full", feedstring);
        }
```

Can anybody spot something anything wrong?

**EDIT:**
It turns out StartTime/EndTime works correctly. I don't really understand what the difference is though and i can't seem to find anything in the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to use StartTime/EndTime instead. Still don't know when to use StartDate and EndDate instead, but that did solve my issue.